# Dealing with zero's while log transformation (subject to other constraints) in R

Tags: r, transformation, logarithm

I have a situation where I need to log transform my data to work with it, but there are zero's in my matrix. In addition to the zero's, the matrix I have is also drawn from the Dirichlet distribution, meaning that the matrix has the constraint that all columnwise sums have to add up to 1. Here is the data:

```
> q[1:10, 1:5]
            V1          V2          V3           V4           V5
1  0.534410243 0.009358740 0.011295181 0.2141751740 0.0030129254
2  0.026653603 0.372426720 0.447847534 0.0179177507 0.4072904477
3  0.193317915 0.003605024 0.003186611 0.4832114736 0.0007095471
4  0.111881585 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.2296213741 0.0119233461
5  0.089696570 0.591163629 0.509774416 0.0032542030 0.5535847030
6  0.007543558 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.0364907757 0.0013148362
7  0.004862942 0.000000000 0.002123909 0.0146682272 0.0004053690
8  0.009276195 0.011710457 0.014367894 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
9  0.006903171 0.004314528 0.011404455 0.0000000000 0.0126889937
10 0.015454219 0.007420903 0.000000000 0.0006610215 0.0090698319
```

Notice that all the columns of q add upto one

```
> colSums(q)[1:5]
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
 1  1  1  1  1
```

I need to take log(q) like so:

```
> log(q)[1:10, 1:5]
           V1         V2         V3         V4         V5
1  -0.6265915 -4.6714446 -4.4833791 -1.5409610 -5.8048438
2  -3.6248309 -0.9877150 -0.8033024 -4.0219634 -0.8982287
3  -1.6434192 -5.6254270 -5.7487974 -0.7273009 -7.2508837
4  -2.1903142       -Inf       -Inf -1.4713235 -4.4292569
5  -2.4113228 -0.5256624 -0.6737870 -5.7278079 -0.5913405
6  -4.8870614       -Inf       -Inf -3.3106958 -6.6340431
7  -5.3261117       -Inf -6.1544972 -4.2220715 -7.8107129
8  -4.6803038 -4.4472730 -4.2427592       -Inf       -Inf
9  -4.9757744 -5.4457675 -4.4737512       -Inf -4.3670203
10 -4.1698733 -4.9034546       -Inf -7.3217241 -4.7028016
```

As you can see, there are a ton of -Inf values that are messing up my calculations. I've thought of replacing the zero's with very small numbers, but then the sum is no longer 1 across columns. How do I write code to construct an alternative matrix to q that 1) doesn't have zero values and therefore bypasses the log(0) problem, and 2) still has columns that add upto one and doesn't change the underlying distribution of the data across the rows?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: To provide a bit of a broader context: I need to take a log transform since I am feeding the output into calculating a log likelihood function. In my application, I am re-parametrizing the log likelihood of the Dirichlet distribution hence I am not calling a generic log likelihood function from a package.

Here is what my overall function looks like:

```
llikelihood = function(alpha0, beta, q, d, n) {
  llike = n*(lgamma(alpha0) - sum_a(alpha0, beta, d) + sum_b (alpha0, beta, q, d, n))
  return(llike)
}

sum_a = function(alpha0, beta, d) {
  sum_a = 0
  for (i in 1:d) {
    sum_a = sum_a + lgamma(alpha0*beta[i]) 
  }
  return(sum_a)
}

# returns the output to summation from 1 to k of (alpha0*beta[i] - 1)*log(x_i)
sum_b = function(alpha0, beta, q, d, n) { 
  # replace zero values
  sum_b = 0
  # find the log q
  logq = log(q)
  qlog = apply(logq, 1, sum)
  #  for each column, sum up the draws
  for (i in 1:d) {
    sum_b = sum_b + (alpha0*beta[i] - 1)*1/n*qlog[i]
  }

  # apply(log(q), 2, sum)
  return(sum_b)
}
```

Here, `sum_b` is where I calculate the log(q) as mentioned above. As you can see, my problem is I need to get rid of the zeros, normalize the data to one, and then take log of that. How can I write code that does it efficiently? I'm guessing it would be like Laplace Smoothing but I don't know much about it and am new to programming in R. Many thanks for the comments!

Comment: 1) Take another transformation, such as square root or cube root. 2) Rescale?

Comment: Once the data is log transformed, it will no longer sum to 1 within columns, regardless of the -Inf issue. .

Comment: this may be an "X-Y" problem; giving us a broader context for the question might get you more useful answers.

Comment: Hi, taking another transformation is difficult because of the context of my code (I've added more details above). I don't need the column sums to be 1 after the log transform, only need it before the log transform to ensure Q still represents draws from a Dirichlet disitribution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) You can try other transformations that don't return -Inf with zeros, such as square root or cube root.

2) Normalize the result from 1) by dividing all elements by their column sums.

```
set.seed(123)
X <- t(rdirichlet(4, alpha=c(1,0,2,1)))
X
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.03562445 0.3384606 0.5700819 0.01357789
[2,] 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000
[3,] 0.64748450 0.2927702 0.3297736 0.88378152
[4,] 0.31689105 0.3687692 0.1001445 0.10264059

colSums(X)
# [1] 1 1 1 1
```

Step 1) Square root.

```
X2 <- sqrt(X); X2
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.1887444 0.5817737 0.7550377 0.1165242
[2,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[3,] 0.8046642 0.5410824 0.5742592 0.9400966
[4,] 0.5629308 0.6072637 0.3164561 0.3203757
```

Step 2) Normalize

```
X3 <- sweep(X2, 2, colSums(X2), FUN="/"); X3

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.1212746 0.3362621 0.4587794 0.08462201
[2,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000
[3,] 0.5170236 0.3127428 0.3489340 0.68271531
[4,] 0.3617018 0.3509952 0.1922865 0.23266269

> colSums(X3)
[1] 1 1 1 1
```